# AngularJS and proper use of ngCloak

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quote from one of the comments regarding `ngCloak` directive ([*AngularJS documentation*](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)):

> It is only really needed on your "index.html" page, because the
>   browser may try to render things before Angular has had a chance to
>   parse/compile it. At runtime, when Angular pulls in content due to
>   ng-view, ng-include, etc., it will be processed by Angular before the
>   browser renders.

I created a example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twSTM/) to verify this and on my surprise the expression is not evaluated before it is rendered in the browser. I would expect that the template will first be compiled & linked and then attached to the DOM - which is not the case.

Does that mean that every `{{expression}}` inside templates should also be wrapped in `ngCloak` to prevent flickering or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the alert allow the browser to render before angular finished his job, adding a setTimeout with 0 delay show a rendered template:

http://jsfiddle.net/g/FLZZR/5/

```
function TemplateController ($scope) {    
    $scope.expression = "This should already be rendered...";
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("... but it isn't.");
    });
}
```

Additional note: you can't expect the template to be rendered at the point you place your alert, at best it would be hidden, angular use dirty checking to do its magic and you must let it "digest" your changes for them to show in the DOM.

Comment: You are right on that.. Maybe it wasn't best example I provided (just fixed it)... I understand that "digest" cycle is needed for template to be rendered.. But I expected (like I already said) that template will be compiled & linked first and then added to the DOM - if that was the case, there would be no change in the DOM before alert pops up. So it looks like it doesn't matter whether the page is initially loaded or whether it is templates loaded later by Angular - `ngCloak` should be used exactly the same way, right?

Comment: It matters because you cannot view the unrendered template if you don't "break" angular lifecycle (with the alert) so it doesn't matter that it's attached to the DOM, not sure I'm clear but it's hard to explain

Comment: but you can view an unrendered template before angular is "booted", it's the purpose of ng-cloak

Comment: Ahh.. Scratch that.. I understand you.. So there is (indeed) no need to use `ngCloak` inside template as it is rendered so fast that it's impossible to notice anything... But it is also true that is is not compiled & linked before added to the DOM...

Comment: Yes :) Actually it's not rendered at all because javascript execution is preventing the browser from rendering.